# What is the part after "catch" called?

Tags: try-catch, terminology, catch-block

What do we call the code highlighted in yellow?

[image: example]

in code it would be:

```
try{
    ...
} catch (Exception $e) { // the part within the brakets
    ...
}
```

I was thinking "catch expression" maybe, but I don't think I have ever read that anywhere.

Comment: Please don't post your code as an image. It's hard to read, prevents text-based searching, and lowers the overall presentation value of the post.

Answer (score 3):

The expression you ask about is the [catch clause](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-18.html)
which, in Java and many other languages, consists of the `CatchType` and `Identifier` and `Block`

> ```
> CatchClause:  
>     catch ( {VariableModifier} CatchType Identifier ) Block
> ```

in [Java](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/catch.html), [C#](https://books.google.de/books?id=euV7e2f-RzsC&pg=PA439&lpg=PA439&dq=%22catch+parameter%22&source=bl&ots=LFx8U9JdHG&sig=tKgdfK-_i6SZWNfTlL1vFe9QnEg&hl=de&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwj3zZfV7t_fAhWF2KQKHboIB_IQ6AEwCXoECAAQAQ#v=onepage&q=%22catch's%20parameter%22&f=false) and [C++](https://books.google.de/books?id=0VoHAAAAQBAJ&pg=PA569&lpg=PA569&dq=%22catch%20parameter%22&source=bl&ots=IVywrJlyG5&sig=wOgzvIgSsXpQk54zbxGD1WEA_yM&hl=de&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjlp66D7d_fAhUMKuwKHQpsDOUQ6AEwCHoECAEQAQ#v=onepage&q=%22catch%20parameter%22&f=false) the `CatchType` and `Identifier` part is typically called

> **catch parameter**

It might be called differently in other languages, but I think *catch parameter* is very descriptive.

Sometimes it is also [called](https://javascript.info/try-catch) the

> error object

[or](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/try...catch), [or](https://help.semmle.com/wiki/display/CSHARP/Rethrowing+exception+variable)

> exception variable

Answer (score 1):

The name of all parts is ***A catch block*** or ***catch statement*** and the yellow part called ***ReferenceError*** ,  ***Exception Handler*** or ***the error object*** .

"Try" and "catch" are keywords that represent the handling of exceptions due to data or coding errors during program execution. A try block is the block of code in which exceptions occur. ***A catch block*** catches and handles try block exceptions.

The try/catch statement is used in many programming languages, including C programming language (C++ and C#), Java, JavaScript and Structured Query Language (SQL).

Try defines a block of statements that may throw an exception. When a specific type of exception occurs, a catch block catches the exception. If an exception is not handled by try/catch blocks, the exception escalates through the call stack until the exception is caught or an error message is printed by the compiler.

A try/catch block also may be nested with one or more try/catch statements. Each try statement has a matching catch statement to handle the exception. If an exception's inner try statement does not have a matching catch statement, subsequent try statement catch handlers are checked. This process continues until all inner try statements are checked for a matching catch statement. If a catch statement does not match, the runtime system handles the exception.

Try/catch block examples include:

1. A try block followed by a catch block
2. A try block followed by one or  more catch blocks
3. A try block followed by another try block and then
   followed by a corresponding catch block

**catch**
When an error occurs, programming language generates an object containing the details about it. The object is then passed as an argument to catch:

For all built-in errors, ***the error object*** inside catch block has two main properties:

**name**
Error name. For an undefined variable that’s "ReferenceError".
**message**
Textual message about error details.
There are other non-standard properties available in most environments. One of most widely used and supported is:

**stack**
Current call stack: a string with information about the sequence of nested calls that led to the error. Used for debugging purposes.

**Sources:**
https://www.techopedia.com/definition/25641/trycatch-block

https://javascript.info/try-catch

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/catch.html

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/exceptions/how-to-use-the-try-catch-block-to-catch-exceptions

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/try...catch